# repaint not being called

Tags: java, swing, repaint, paintcomponent, event-dispatch-thread

Hi I have googled and can't figured out why my paintComp method isnt being called

I have the following code
package com.vf.zepto.view;

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import com.vf.zepto.view.interfaces.ProcessorPanel;

public class CountryDetailsPanel extends JPanel implements ProcessorPanel, Runnable {
    private GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    private String countryName;
    private Properties prop = new Properties();
    private BufferedImage image;

    public CountryDetailsPanel() {
        try {
            prop.load(new FileInputStream("country.props"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        c.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);

        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        try {
            if(countryName != null) {
                String asset = prop.getProperty(countryName+".flag");

                if(!asset.equals(null)) {
                    image = ImageIO.read(new File(asset));
                    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
                }
            }
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void updateDetails(Object o) {
        countryName = (String)o;
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        this.repaint();
    }
}
```

and when calling `this.repaint()` expect the `paintComponent` method to be called but for love nor money it isnt.

Have tried to force it to use the EDT incase that was the issue but its not.

any ideas?

Comment: +1 for ** for love nor money it isnt**. Though what exactly is the extension of the image in question ?

Comment: Looks like paint should call paintComponent.
http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/GUI-lowlevel/graphics/15who-calls-paintcomponent.html
May help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- You should never call `paintComponent()` the `repaint()` method consolidates all requests to change the component (there may be several repaint requests between screen refreshes). It adds an update request to the GUI event queue so that the update will be properly coordinated with other GUI actions (Swing and AWT are not thread-safe). This update request, when processed, calls `update()`, which calls `paint()`, which calls your `paintComponent()`
- Why have this:

  ```
  @Override
  public void run() {
      this.repaint();
     }
  ```

It does not seem of any use (creating a new thread to repaint once? Not to mention the thread is not on EDT rather call `repaint()` on the `JPanel` instance (if modified externally other than that you shouldnt even worry). However to start a thread which modifeis UI componets use s `SwingTimer`/`SwingWorker` or `SwingUtilities#invokeXXX()`

- This might not be related but in your code I see this:

  ```
          if(!asset.equals(null)) {
              image = ImageIO.read(new File(asset));
              g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
          }
  ```

dont use `equals()` to compare to a `null` value as this might throw a `NullPointerException` because you are attempting to
deference a null pointer, for example this code throws a `NPE`:

```
    String s=null;
    if(!s.equals(null)) {//throws NPE
        System.out.println("Here");//is never printed
    }
```

- Also as mKorbel has said (+1 to him) dont do long running tasks in `paintComponent()` declare your `Image` globally, assign it in the constructor and then use it in `paintComponent()`. F.i

rather do:

```
public class TestPanel extends JPanel {

private Image image;

public TestPanel() {
image = ImageIO.read(new File(asset));
}

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
                if(asset!=null) {
                    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
                }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for the wonderful set of information, though calling repaint() from within the paintComponent() is not a good thought, since while performing painting related stuff, it came into the paintComponent() method and here again we are sending Swing back to paint the whole thing again for no reason. Paint is a heavy task. A quote from Filthy Rich Client can justify that a bit

Comment: **It is important to note that repaint requests get “coalesced,” or combined. So, for example, if you request a repaint and there is already one on the queue that has not yet been serviced, then the second request is ignored because your request for a repaint will already be fulﬁlled by the earlier request. This behavior is particularly helpful in situations where many repaint requests are being generated, perhaps by very different situations and components, and Swing should avoid processing redundant requests and wasting effort.**

Comment: @gagandeepbali +1 thank you, and thank you for the new facts on repaint. Keep smilin :)

Comment: You're MOST WELCOME and KEEP SMILING :-)

Comment: @mKorbel +1 Hahaha Oh how I am glad a few oceans separate us :P. Edited code thank you

Comment: wow, that put me straight! cheers for the info though! i realise the issue with null and changed it before reading this.

Answer (score 5):

1. Do *not* load image or another hard or long running code in `paintComponent`
2. Load this `Object` as a local variable and only one time
3. `paintComponent()` is called

   - implicitly, when `JComponent` requires repaint, or
   - explicitly, for example on every of mouse event if one were to invoke `paintComponent()` from a `MouseMotionListener`.
4. If there is animation, then to use Swing Timer and call `repaint()`.

Comment: @mKorbel : Please do explain me the meaning of e.i. as in point 3rd :-) Isn't it i.e. which stands for **that is** ?

Comment: Guessing: a mixture of _exempli gratia_ and _for instance_?

Comment: @Gagandeep Bali put there System.out.println(), crazy number of events are fired from everywhere, phaaaa or I something miss in your comment :-),